# c - char array isn't printing every value

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I am currently creating an encryption/decryption application as practice, and to do that I have been trying to convert an integer into a char array using snprintf however, for example, if I have an integer with 4 digits, it only adds the first 3. Here is my code so far:

```
int encrypt(int num, bool type)
{
    char buffer[sizeof(num)];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", num);
    printf(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `char buffer[snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", num)+1];`

Comment: Please read what the `sizeof` operator does.

Comment: snprintf will only write sizeof(buffer)-1 characters into your buffer, since it needs to leave space for the null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer should have a size large enough to hold the digits of the conversion plus a final `'\0'` and a potential minus sign.  `sizeof(num)` is the number of bytes for the `int` variable, most likely `4`, not enough for the conversion of numbers larger than 999, but `snprintf` will not write more than the size of the buffer including the final `'\0'`, hence only the first 3 digits.

You can either make an assumption on the size of `int` and define `buffer` as:

```
char buffer[12]; /* large enough for -2147483648 */
```

Or you can do it precisely and portably:

```
char buffer[sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 3];
```

Comment: I doubt the OP wants sizeof(num) here, since that value is independent of the value of num. If that's really what he wants, he should use `sizeof int`

Comment: @FredK: I don't agree: using `sizeof(num)` is advisable as it works regardless of the actual integer type, which may be later changed to `long` or even `long long`.  Duplicating the type is a common cause of bugs when the type is changed in one place and not in others.